# Reiser4: completely disable journaling

Tags: linux, filesystems, sd-card, journaling

How can journaling be completely disabled in a Reiser4 filesystem?
I don't see relevant options in `mkfs.reiser4`, nor in documentations.

The goal is to fit the FS into an SD card, where no journal is preferable for endurance.

Answer (score 1):

Better use some filesystem that is suported. Reiser4 was never really completed, and has been abandoned for some years now.

Comment: Instead of kludging a file system that isn't quite working on the storage drive being used, it is better to use a file system that is fully supported by the drivers currently available.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Reiser4 Wiki](https://reiser4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mount), you can use the "nolog" option when mounting the reiser4 partition to "disable" journalling. However:

```
... even with this option turned on, ReiserFS still performs all journalling
paraphernalia, save for actual writes into journalling area. Implementation of 
real nolog is work in progress.
```

Comment: This is specifically for ReiserFS. I'm not able to give feedback as suddenly I found out that my SD controller isn't fully supported by Linux (Texas Instruments PCIxx12)

Comment: No, `nolog` isn't supported by Reiser4. See my own answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Reiser4 has advanced transaction manager which uses a combination of journalling and Copy-on-Write (AKA Write-Anywhere) techniques. It is possible to implement different transaction modes such as pure journalling and pure COW. Also it is possible to disable transactions at all. In the last case you'll need to run fsck every time after hard reset. We'll implement all those possibilities in future Reiser4 releases, so users will be able to specify them via mount options.

The latest stable release of reiser4 and reiser4progs(fsck) can be found here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/reiser4/
If any problems, please send a message to reiserfs-devel at vger.kernel.org mailing list

Thanks,
Edward.

Comment: You didn't really answer the OP's question. He wanted to know how to do this. So are you saying that it's feasible but just not exposed in the options to the user yet or that it's possible but are expecting him/her to ask their question over on the developers forum?  Either way it's hard to follow what you're saying.

Comment: Reiser4 has been abandoned quite some time back, in large part as it promised to do impossible things.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought I heard as well, with the founder going to jail. These wikipedia articles have more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Reiser & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiser4.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it's not possible to disable journaling on a Reiser4.

Reference: http://marc.info/?l=reiserfs-devel&m=128267881622110